# backslash at the beginning of a command

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, shell, alias

In [Installing RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) manual I see a lot of lines starting with '\':

> Install RVM with ruby:
>
> `$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

I'd think it is just mistype but they repeat it many times.

So what is the reason?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691977/why-start-a-shell-command-with-a-backslash

Comment: @tripleee According to "What topics can I ask about here? " for both Serverfault and Stackoverflow, Linux shell questions are better posted here, not there.

Comment: I can't see what makes you believe that. Anyway, the link is just to make visitors aware that there are more and different answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no error, it's a little hack to avoid using a `curl` `shell` [alias](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash#Aliases) if any exists.

This works too :

```
'curl' (...)
"curl" (...)
/usr/bin/curl (...)
command curl (...)
command -p curl (...)
```

Comment: That tells what the backslash does, still not why they put it there... is curl often alias'ed? Otherwise you could put it in any manual before every command.

Comment: maybe they wanted to prevent unwanted options, with an alias like `curl='curl -foo'`

Answer (score 9):

A command preceded by a slash temporarily disables any aliases for the command.

[Bash Shell Temporarily Disable an Alias](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-temporarily-disable-an-alias/)